# Getting inappropriate output with left join

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, left-join

I am trying to get list of variants and for each of this variants get all `subvariants list` irrespective of where subvariants fall for
particular `Test say 100`.This is sample data:

```
Id      TestId    SourceSubVariantId   TargetSubVariantId   DiffPerc
114      100           66              67                   100.00
115      100           67              68                   100.00
116      100           70              71                   99.99
```

I have **3 subvariants for Variants 1** :

```
Id=66,Name=Abc
Id=68,Name=Pqr
Id=69,Name=xyz
```

I have **3 subvariants for Variants 2** :

```
Id=70,Name=lmn
Id=71,Name=xxx
Id=72,Name=hhh
```

But notice in my output in am getting all `Id as 0` for `Variants 2` `subvariants list` in `Variant1 CustomSubvariantList`:

[image]

**Data Model:**

```
public class Variants
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SubVariants> SubVariants { get; set; }
    }

    public class SubVariants
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int VariantId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual Variants Variants { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TestOperation> TestOperation { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TestOperation> TestOperation1 { get; set; }
    }

        public class TestOperation
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> TestId { get; set; }
        public int SourceSubVariantId { get; set; }
        public int TargetSubVariantId { get; set; }
        public decimal DiffPerc { get; set; }
        public virtual SubVariants SubVariants { get; set; }
        public virtual SubVariants SubVariants1 { get; set; }
                public virtual Test Test { get; set; }
    }
```

**Query:**

```
int testId=100;
var query =
      from v in context.Variants 
      where v.Type  == "Add"
      select new
      {
           ParentVariant = v.Name,
           Type = v.Method,
           CustomSubvariantList =
           (
                from svName in context.SubVariants.Select(sv => sv.Name).Distinct()
                join x in
                (
                     from sv in v.SubVariants 
                     from to in sv.TestOperation 
                     where to.TestId == testId
                     orderby sv.Id
                     select new
                     {
                          sv.Name,
                          to.DiffPerc,
                          SourceId = (int?)to.SubVariants.Id,
                          TargetID=(int?)to.SubVariants1.Id
                     }
                 )
                 on svName equals x.Name into g  
                 from x in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 orderby x.SourceId
                 select new
                 {
                      SourceId=x.SourceId ?? 0,
                      TargetId=x.TargetID ?? 0,
                      Name = svName,
                      DiffPerc = x.DiffPerc
                 }
             ).ToList()
         };
```

**Update:** **Based on comments this is the sample inputs and expected output:**

**Case 1**:**When subvariants name are different in all parent variants**

**Variants:**

```
Id      Name       Type   CategoryId
11      Variant1    Add     1
12      Variant2    Add     1
13      Variant3    Add     1
14      Variant4    Add     1
```

**SubVariants:**

```
Id     VariantId     Name
66      11           Abc
67      11           PQR
68      11           Xyz

70      12           lmn
71      12           xxx
72      12           hhh
```

**Test Operation:**

```
Id      TestId    SourceSubVariantId   TargetSubVariantId   DiffPerc
114      100           66               67                  10.00
115      100           67               68                  20.00

114      100           70               71                  40.00
115      100           71               72                  50.00
```

**Expected output**:
[image]

**Case 2**:**When Subvariants name are same in all parents variants:**

**SubVariants:**

```
Id     VariantId     Name
66      11           Abc
67      11           PQR
68      11           Xyz

70      12           Abc
71      12           PQR
72      12           Xyz
```

**Expected Output**:
[image]

Comment: I don't get it why in TestOpeartion you have SubVariants ? you can access to SubVariants  via Variants. also would please explain more what you want

Comment: @MahdiFarhani :In Testoperation notice that SourceSubVariantId  and TargetSubVariantId  which indicates that i have single entry for every 2 subvariants and it means that there is some operation performed between SourceSubVariantId   and TargetSubVariantId and both this property are referenced to SubVariant Primary key

Comment: would you please check   SourceId ==to.SourceSubVariantId instead of SourceId = (int?)to.SubVariants.Id,

Comment: @MahdiFarhani I have already checled that but still not working i.e same result as shown in image

Comment: in your query "on svName equals x.Name into g  from x in g.DefaultIfEmpty()" is a left join so when it's not equal it's return a null value and above that you have subvarient name, because of that you get 0 number in your result. be honest I dont get what do want in real, I think you can achieve your goal with simple query.
you want all varient with subvarient they used in test operation ?Am i right ?

Comment: @MahdiFarhani :i want all variants list along with child variants.eg: i have 3 subvariants for Variant1: abc,pqr and xyz and from this 3 subvariants only abc and xyz are executed in testoperation  and for Variant2:lmn,xxx,hhh and from this 3 only lmn,xxx are executed so when creating variants wise list(parent variant) then for Variants1 list for subvariants i want :6 subvariants with no duplicate subvariants and for Variant2 i want again 6 total subvariants along with variants1 subvariants list with no duplicate subvariants i.e two subvariants name cant be same for Variants1 list vice versa

Comment: If you can provide a depiction of your desired output, that would make things easier. I can't tell if the red arrows are explaining why something is empty or why it shouldn't be.

Comment: @MachineLearning More information can be found in a deleted answer... http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118593/discussion-between-lucian-bumb-and-learning

Comment: @MahdiFarhani :See my updated question with sample inputs and output

Comment: @Chee'sBurgers:See my updated question with sample inputs and output

Comment: @MachineLearning:See my updated question with sample inputs and output

Comment: @Aron:See my updated question with sample inputs and output

Comment: @MachineLearning : Yes i have context.TestOperation and did you understand now whole process of what i am trying to achieve??

Comment: I don't think the expected output is correct. How could `'hhh'` possibly correlate to source `70` target `71`. Also, if `'xxx'` does indeed correlate to source `70` and target `71`, that means your query has to check the subvariant Id against both the target and source ids from the test results.

Comment: Please provide information to reproduce this issue: database version, framework version

Comment: @Chee'sBurgers Can you please tell me for which case you are talking about.Case 1 or case 2??

Comment: @profimedica what does database version and framework have to do with this problem but still i am using sql server database and framework is .net 4.5

Comment: case 1. `hhh` is id `72`. How can it correlate to source `70` and target `71`. I don't see the relationship except for the fact that they are all variant id  `12`.

Comment: @Chee'sBurgers Oops sorry there a mistake in last record for Case 1.Correct is Source Id:71 and TargetId:72 for hhh

Comment: @MachineLearning:No problem.its totally fine but still i really appreciate your efforts towards helping me

Comment: Case 1: Is `pqr` (id `67`) supposed to correlate to source `66` target `67` or source `67` target `68`. There seems to be a bit of ambiguity here because you are trying to join tests to subvariants on both source ID and target ID.

Comment: @Chee'sBurgers :If you want i can give you dummy database and demo project

Comment: Downvoters please atleast care to comment your reason for downvoting.i just dont understand sometimes that i have showed my efforts for solving the problem and apart from that explained this question very well but seems like some users are here on SO for just downvoting instead of helping

Comment: Aside from anything else, it would be easier to help you if you reduced this to a *minimal* example. I'm sure you don't really need a total of 18 properties in order to demonstrate this. A short but *complete* example which compiled and ran (including the sample data) would be helpful too.

Comment: @jon skeet:At first I have given a short and minimal example but based on lots of comments I have given a sample inputs and yes the dropbox link contains compiled and runnable example along with the same database which contains exact data I have given here.if you could download it  and run it you will see that it is running fine but yes I will remove my data model part if you are saying because you are the top user of SO :)

Comment: It's not a matter of removing it - it's a matter of reducing it to just what is required. You should also post the expected output as *text* rather than as pictures (which are harder to view in general). When a question takes 5 1/2 pages, that's a pretty good sign it could be reduced...

Comment: @JonSkeet But posting this image as text would make my question again too long that is why i have posted it as image rather than text because i wanted to address 2 important Cases with expected output in both this cases and so posting expected output as text would make my question little big

Comment: If you'd made the problem as small as you could, it wouldn't be too long even when demonstrating two cases, I suspect. Anyway, you asked why people downvoted - I gave the reasons I suspect others did. (I haven't voted either way, and I haven't got time to wade through such an enormous question, personally.)

Comment: Your question is very unclear and too broad. Since your question relates to data in database, you should clearly mention the schema of all tables being used in your LINQ query rather than leave it to reader's imagination.  You mention a table at start of your question and then talk about Variant1/Variant2, but where is the schema for Variants table.  Also it's very unclear why you have two SubVariant columns in your first table. Break your BIG problem into simpler parts and then decide which part is causing your issues.

Comment: If you look up LINQ questions on stackoverflow you will notice that they are very specific in what is the issue being faced by the developer.

Comment: I think the down votes may have been because you seem to be asking something like this: `can someone on stackoverflow do my homework`.  Even though your intentions may not have been this,  it would help you a lot if you asked a more narrowed down question. Then I am sure these down votes would not have been there.

Comment: You should look up this question to see how parent-child can be determined using LINQ from a  single database table: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994383/how-to-return-both-parent-and-child-using-linq-against-1-table. In your case, whatever I could understand from your post, it seems you have a single table and you want to determine from that single table the  Variants (i.e. parents) and SubVariants (i.e. children).

Comment: @sunil if it would have been that somebody please do my homework then I would not  have tried anything and simply leave to the SO users for solving my problem but instead I have clearly shown what I have tried and not like please write whole query for me but yes next time I will surely remember this next time.Than you :)

Comment: @sunil talking about schema structure I have put all the required table which have been addressed in my query.can you please point out the table which I have left to readers imagination??

Comment: Like I said, your intentions may not have been like that, but that is the message some users on  stackoverflow may have got.

Comment: How many tables in database will your LINQ query use is still unknown after reading your question. Your question is lacking a lot of information.  You have to be more clear in your question.

Comment: @sunil sorry to say but it is clear that 3 tables are used in my query.Variants,subvariants,Testoperation

Comment: It is clear to you but I can bet its not to others. Did you mention that you are using 4 tables with given schema in your LINQ query? `Even the first guy who tried to answer you had to get into a long chat with you.` A question should be easy enough to understand just by reading it without the need of any chat.

Comment: Take the downvotes in a constructive manner and try to improve your question quality. I have also been downvoted many times.

Comment: @sunil Thank you so much for your kind suggestions. I will surely keep this in mind when asking question next time

Comment: TLDR - EF is best without Joins and you are supposed to use navigation properties !!!

Comment: @AkashKava Why according to you EF is best without joins??

Comment: @Learning joins are automatically created by EF if you query using navigation properties, it gives you better understanding and more readable query in terms of relationships between objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We had some discussions on chat till I understood what you want.

this is the code:

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        VariantsEntities db=new VariantsEntities();

        var queryResult = db.Variants.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new PageViewModel
        {
            ParentVariant = x.Name,
            Type = x.Type,
            CustomSubvariantList = GetCustomSubVariants(x.Id,db).ToList()
        }).ToList();


        var jsonObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(queryResult);
        Console.WriteLine(jsonObj);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Customsubvariantlist> GetCustomSubVariants(int variantId, VariantsEntities db)
    {
        var subVariants = db.SubVariants.ToList();

        foreach (var subVariant in subVariants)
        {
            var obj=new Customsubvariantlist();
            obj.Name = subVariant.Name;

            var testOpTarget = db.TestOperations
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.TargetSubVariantId == subVariant.Id);
            var testOpSource = db.TestOperations
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.SourceSubVariantId == subVariant.Id);

            if (subVariant.VariantId == variantId)
            {
                obj.Value = testOpTarget == null ? 
                    testOpSource?.SourceValue : testOpTarget?.TargetValue;
                obj.DiffPerc = testOpTarget?.DiffPerc;
            }
            else
            {
                obj.Value = null;
                obj.DiffPerc = null;
            }
            yield return obj;
        }

    }
}
```

you just need to replace the DbContext name, and test it.

this is the result:

```
    [
  {
    "ParentVariant": "Variant1",
    "Type": "Add",
    "CustomSubvariantList": [
      {
        "Name": "Abc",
        "Value": 200,
        "DiffPerc": null
      },
      {
        "Name": "Pqr",
        "Value": 300,
        "DiffPerc": 100.0
      },
      {
        "Name": "xyz",
        "Value": 500,
        "DiffPerc": 200.0
      },
      {
        "Name": "lmn",
        "Value": null,
        "DiffPerc": null
      },
      {
        "Name": "xxx",
        "Value": null,
        "DiffPerc": null
      },
      {
        "Name": "hhh",
        "Value": null,
        "DiffPerc": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ParentVariant": "Variant2",
    "Type": "Add",
    "CustomSubvariantList": [
      {
        "Name": "Abc",
        "Value": null,
        "DiffPerc": null
      },
      {
        "Name": "Pqr",
        "Value": null,
        "DiffPerc": null
      },
      {
        "Name": "xyz",
        "Value": null,
        "DiffPerc": null
      },
      {
        "Name": "lmn",
        "Value": 1000,
        "DiffPerc": null
      },
      {
        "Name": "xxx",
        "Value": 2000,
        "DiffPerc": 1000.0
      },
      {
        "Name": "hhh",
        "Value": 4000,
        "DiffPerc": 2000.0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

From [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/29wen8vbv6xrus3/Variants.7z?dl=0) you can download the sample project. This project was done with the sample database you sent me, so is Database First and is possible that some props or tables to have a different name, please check this before moving the code in your project.

Basically what I did:

1. created a new console app project
2. I got the model from your json object (I copied the json object and pase it in a class, using (vs menu) Edit -> Past Special -> Past JSON as Classes.
3. Since you want all `SubVariants` for each `Varian`, I created a separate method to handle the rules which you had for creating the `CustomSubVariantList`. In this method I iterate throw all SubVariants and I created objects base on your conditions.

**Update:** your solution in one query:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        VariantsEntities db = new VariantsEntities();

        var result = from x in db.Variants                        
                     select new PageViewModel
                     {
                         ParentVariant = x.Name,
                         Type = x.Type,
                         CustomSubvariantList = (from z in db.SubVariants
                                                 let testOpTarget=z.TestOperations1
                                                        .FirstOrDefault(q=>q.TargetSubVariantId==z.Id)
                                                 let testOpSource=z.TestOperations
                                                        .FirstOrDefault(q=>q.SourceSubVariantId==z.Id)
                                                 select new Customsubvariantlist
                                                 {
                                                     Name = z.Name,
                                                     Value = x.Id==z.VariantId? 
                                                             testOpTarget.TargetValue??
                                                             testOpSource.SourceValue:null,
                                                     DiffPerc = x.Id==z.VariantId? 
                                                                testOpTarget.DiffPerc:null
                                                 }).ToList()
                     };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.ToList());
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

this query produce the same result like above method. 
Please let me know if is what you need!!

**Update: this is the query for Case 2**

```
 var result = from x in db.Variants
            select new PageViewModel
            {
                ParentVariant = x.Name,
                Type = x.Type,
                CustomSubvariantList = (from z in db.SubVariants.GroupBy(g => g.Name)
                    .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault(d => d.VariantId == x.Id) ?? g.FirstOrDefault())
                    let testOpTarget = z.TestOperations1
                        .FirstOrDefault(q => q.TargetSubVariantId == z.Id)
                    let testOpSource = z.TestOperations
                        .FirstOrDefault(q => q.SourceSubVariantId == z.Id)
                    select new Customsubvariantlist
                    {
                        Name = z.Name,
                        SubVariantId = z.Id,
                        CombineName =(z.TestOperations.Any() || z.TestOperations1.Any())? 
                                      testOpTarget.TargetValue.HasValue? 
                                      testOpTarget.SubVariant.Name+" to "+testOpTarget.SubVariant1.Name : null: "Undefined",
                        Value = x.Id == z.VariantId
                            ? testOpTarget.TargetValue ??
                              testOpSource.SourceValue
                            : null,
                        DiffPerc = x.Id == z.VariantId
                            ? testOpTarget.DiffPerc
                            : null
                    }).OrderBy(k => k.SubVariantId).ToList()
            };
```

Comment: Sorry but your above code is giving me subvariants list of particular parents variants only but this is not i wanted and yes your 2 questions that you have describe in your answer regarding SourceSubVariantId  and TargetSubVariantId  are right.Both are foreign key for Subvariant Id.please see my last comment below my question and the image i have posted in question

Comment: still it is not giving as expected output with 4 subvariants in each variants like :Variant1 :abc,xyz,pqr,lmn and all this 4 have entries in Testoperation like this:abc - xyz,xyz - pqr, pqr - lmn then i am not getting lmn record for parent variant in their subvariant list

Comment: the query is returning all TestOperations with testId=100, please pay attention that you have a second list TestOperations2 in each SubVariant, which are not considered by your query and neither by mine.

Comment: but consider i have 4 parent variants and each variants contains exactly 4 subvariants so total subvariants list is 16 and all this subvariants name are abc,xyz,pqr and lmn then your query will give me 16 subvariants list for each parent variants but here i required is 4 subvariants for each parent variant because i dont want to add duplicate name subvariants in each of parent variant which i am getting with my query

Comment: on what conditions do want to eliminate the subvariants?

Comment: please see the updated query. If I get it correct the old query was returning duplicates in name of SubvariantName, so with this update you should get only once each subvariant name

Comment: At first i was getting error on this line :.SelectMany(x=>x.First()) that a local variable already declare and would give another meaning and so i changed to this :.SelectMany(t=>t.First()) but still getting error on this line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118593/discussion-between-lucian-bumb-and-learning).

Comment: @Learning chack out the solution in one query

Comment: Your query is taking all subvariants from every parent variants even if subvariants name are common across all parent variants.so with your last query i am geting duplicate subvariants name for Variant1 and for other variants also i.e for Variant2 etc..

Comment: can you go in chat?

Answer (score 3):

This is a "variant" of your query.. it extracts all `SubVariants` per `Variant(s)` ordered as they are in the table SubVariants (by their autoseed Sql Server Identity Id), irrespective of `TestOperation` involved and avoid duplicates as your expected outputs.

Unfortunately it isn't possible to have always all subvariants designated as source and tartget subvariant, because this information depends on testoperation, in fact testop decides if a subvar is "source" or "target". So, if some subvariants isn't included into testoperations records/entity then they cannot appear as source or target.. a workaround could be to attach, next to "Name" property of anonymous type returned, also "Id SubVar"

I added 2 DTOs because entity framework doesn't allow using `distinct().ToList()` method to preserve order and apply custom distinct rule, so I added a step more to pass from Link To EF at Link To Object through dto objects and in this way make possible the applying the distinct custom rule..

```
    public class CustomerVariantDTO
    {
        public String Type;
        public String ParentVariant;
        public IEnumerable<CustomerSubVariantDTO> CustomSubvariantList;
    }

    public class CustomerSubVariantDTO
    {
        public int? VariantId;
        public int? SubVariantId;
        public int? SourceId;
        public int? TargetId;
        public String Name;
        public Decimal? DiffPerc;
    }

    sealed class CustomerSubVariantDTOComparer : IEqualityComparer<CustomerSubVariantDTO>
    {
        public int GetHashCode(CustomerSubVariantDTO obj)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        public bool Equals(CustomerSubVariantDTO x, CustomerSubVariantDTO y)
        {
            return x.SourceId == y.SourceId &&
                   x.TargetId == y.TargetId &&
                   x.Name == y.Name &&
                   x.DiffPerc == y.DiffPerc;

        }
    }


    public void DoTestOfCustomerVariantDTO()
    {
        int testId = 1;
        using (var context = new VariantsEntities())
        {
            var query =
              (from v in context.Variants
               where v.Type == "Add"
               select new CustomerVariantDTO
               {
                   ParentVariant = v.Name,
                   Type = v.Type,
                   CustomSubvariantList =
                   (
                     from sv in context.SubVariants.Select(sv => sv)
                     join x in
                     (
                         from svparent in v.SubVariants
                         from to in svparent.TestOperation
                         where to.TestId == testId
                         select new
                         {
                             svparent.Name,
                             to.DiffPerc,
                             SourceId = (int?)to.SubVariants.Id ?? 0,
                             TargetId = (int?)to.SubVariants1.Id ?? 0
                         }
                     )
                     on sv.Name equals x.Name into g
                     from x in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new CustomerSubVariantDTO{
                         VariantId = sv.VariantId,
                         SubVariantId = sv.Id,
                         SourceId = (int?)x.SourceId ?? sv.TestOperation.Select(to => to.SourceSubVariantId).FirstOrDefault(),
                         TargetId = (int?)x.TargetId ?? sv.TestOperation.Select(to => to.TargetSubVariantId).FirstOrDefault(),
                         Name = sv.Name,
                         DiffPerc = x.DiffPerc
                     }
                  ).OrderBy(csv => new { csv.VariantId, csv.SubVariantId })
               }).ToList();

            var listCustomVariants =
                query.Select(v => new{
                    Type = v.Type,
                    ParentVariant = v.ParentVariant,
                    CustomSubvariantList = v.CustomSubvariantList.Distinct(new CustomerSubVariantDTOComparer()).ToList()
                });

            foreach (var item in listCustomVariants){
                Console.WriteLine($"Type: {item.Type} - ParentVariant: {item.ParentVariant} ");
                foreach (var csubvar in item.CustomSubvariantList)
                    Console.WriteLine($"SourceId: {csubvar.SourceId} - TargetiId: {csubvar.TargetId} - NAme: {csubvar.Name} - DiffPerc: {csubvar.DiffPerc} ");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but still i am not getting last Subvariant Id.It is still null

Comment: See my updated question in which i have included demo source code along with the database file in case if you want to check out the output in your environment

Comment: With this query I get exactly the 2 expetcted outputs in the PO, all subvariant with different names and all subvariant of a variant with names equal to subvariants of others variants

Comment: Please notice last record of SubvariantId which is coming null.Notice that SourceId and TargetId are coming as 0 for Subvariant xyz

Comment: ! more thing that i would like to have same ordering for Subvariants list and with the aove query i am getting Xyz at the top but if you will see in Subvariant table xyz is the last subvariant for Variant 1

Comment: Hi Learning, sorry I had added a comment but I see that something is gone wrong.. anyway I figured out your problem.. unfortunately it isn't possible to have always all subvariants designated as source and tartget subvariant, because this information depends on testoperation, in fact testop decides if a subv is a source or target. So, if some subvariants isn't included into testoperations records/entity then they cannot appear as source or target.. a workaround could be attach next to "Name" svar also "Id SubVar".. I aupdated my answer upon witn some adjstment about entity-frmwk compatibility

Comment: Duplicate issue is solved but still i am not getting the exact order as i have in Subvariant table of subvariants